# label and add legends on density plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, density-plot

I am trying to draw two density graphs on the same plot. I tried the following code.

```
car     Bus
48.1    17.8
47.2    21.2
69.9    27
72.7    9.1
73.8    23.9
67.7    4.9
61.1    12.3
61.6    0.4
        4.7
        20.9
        5.5
        19.8
         5.9
        14.3
        16.3


 library(ggplot2)
m <-ggplot()+geom_density(aes(data$column1),color='red')+geom_density(aes(data$column2), color='blue')
```

The code gives what I want. But I have to label x-axis and also need to add legends. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What does documentation say on this subject?

Comment: I don't see any data. Please post at least some of your data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should stack your two variables together and have a factor variable saying which column it is. Then you can add your labels and choose your colors like this:

```
data <- read.table(text = "
column1 column2
48.1    17.8
47.2    21.2
69.9    27
72.7    9.1
73.8    23.9
67.7    4.9
61.1    12.3
61.6    0.4
NA        4.7
NA        20.9
NA        5.5
NA        19.8
NA         5.9
NA        14.3
NA        16.3", header = TRUE)
plot.data <- data.frame(x      = c(data$column1, data$column2),
                        column = paste("column", rep(c(1:2), each = nrow(df))))
library(ggplot2)
m <-ggplot(plot.data, aes(x = x, fill = column)) + geom_density(alpha = 0.5) +
  xlab("My x label") + ylab("My y label") +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "My legend title", values = c("red", "blue"))
```

[image]

Comment: How can I add legends as car and bus instead of column1 and column2?

Comment: You can use `column = c(rep("car", nrow(data)), rep("bus", nrow(data)))` inside instead of what's there